# Calling function defined in an object

Tags: javascript

I have an object that defines the name and parameters of a function to be called in the click event of a page element.

```
object_array = [
    {
       id: "id1",
       onclick: "load_file(filename.php);",
    },

    {
       id: "id2",
       onclick: "open_url('http://url.com');",
    }
];
```

That information must be retrieved dynamically.  I'd like in the click event to call the onclick function for a given object in the array.

```
$('element').click(function() {
      // call object.onclick
});
```

Seems that eval() is not a good choice.  Is there a different way of calling that function?

Comment: So `object_array` is retrieved from the server in JSON or similar?  Or is it simply a literal embedded in your code?

Comment: Do you have any control over the objects in `object_array`? In other words, can you change the format of `onclick` into something reasonable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refactor the `object_array` to:

```
[{
    id: "id1",
    action: "load_file",
    url: "filename.php"
}, {
   id: "id2",
   action: "open_url",
   url: 'http://url.com'
}];
```

Then you can call it with:

```
var actions = {
    load_file: function(url) {
        ...
    },
    open_url: function(url) {
        ...
    },
    ...
};
object_array.forEach(function(ob) {
    $("#"+ob.id).click(function() {
        actions[ob.action](ob.url);
    });
});
```

If you have more complex arguments, you could also deliver an arguments array instead of `url` and use [`apply()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) on the function.

---

Or, if you just want a lookup-table of functions, use:

```
var object = {
    "id1": function() {
        load_file('filename.php');
    },
    "id2": function() {
        open_url('http://url.com');
    }
};
$('element').click(function() {
    object[this.id]();
});
```

Comment: The lookup-table of functions was enough for me. This was a good solution for me.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zh6Fv/1/

Like so:

```
 object_array = [
        {
           id: "id1",
           // Encapsulate in an anonymous function
           onclick: function(){ load_file('filename.php'); },
        },
        {
           id: "id2",
           // Encapsulate in an anonymous function
           onclick: function(){ open_url('http://url.com'); },
        }
    ];
```

Then actually bind it it like this ::

```
$('element').click(obj.onclick);
```

Presumably you would be using it like this::

```
object_array.forEach(function(obj){
     // Note there is no need to wrap the obj.onclick
     // into another anonymous function anymore!
     $("#" + obj.id).click(obj.onclick);
});
```

Here's a working jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Zh6Fv/1/

Comment: If I were to call the onclick inside a another function would this be `function name() { object.onclick; }`?  Thanks.

Comment: if you want to call it, then you call it like `function name() { object.onclick(); }` just like you would a normal function! :)

Comment: My object array did  not like the anonymous function within the object.  It didn't like the `onclick: function () {load_file('filename.php');},`.

Comment: @user823527 I've added a jsfiddle link for you

Comment: This does work in the fiddle.  But when called inside a function other than the click function, the object.onclick isn't done.  `function name() { object.onclick; }` doesn't actually run the load_file() function.

Comment: @user823527 Yes your code must look like `function name() { object.onclick(); }` Note the added brackets to 'onclick'

Comment: Before you made the update to add the brackets, I looked at his solutions and found the way that worked from there.  Also, I thought if someone where to read this question for an answer it'd be clearer for them to read the look-up table solution.  All the information is there.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare a function like

```
onclick : function()
{
   action(arguments);
}
```